# Why nodemailer doesn't work on AWS Server -NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mean-stack, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer 0.7.1 and I can sent emails on my localhost. But when I use it with AWS Server, didn't get any such mail. Please help me.

```
  var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
     service: "Gmail",
     auth: {
         user: "from@gmail.com",
         pass: "**************"
     }
   });
  var mail = {
         from   : "from@gmail.com",
         to     : "to@gmail.com",
         subject    : "dummy subject",
         html   : "dummy message"
     }

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
     if(error){
         console.log(error+"console error");
         smtpTransport.close();
     } else{
         logger.info("Mail sent: " + response.message);
         smtpTransport.close();

    }
```

Comment: Have you opened the ports?

Comment: which port number I need to opened?

Comment: 456 for gmail ssl smtp

Comment: I added that, but still I could not send message

Comment: any updation on this

Comment: I am about to try OAuth 2.0 key approach. As described here ...`https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/` If it does not work, I have to go to AWS's long learning path's SES approach